# Jackson JSON deserialization to java.util.Date not working

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, deserialization

We are trying to send java.util.Date objects to our REST resource but Jackson deserializes the JSON string for the incoming date `1348696800000` to a Date with the value `163469056-01-01 00:00:00.0`. What could be the problem?

Our REST resource:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response create(A a) {
}
```

The POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {
    private Date startDate;
}
```

The JSON:

```
{ ... "startDate":1348696800000, ... }
```

If Jackson serializes a Date into Milliseconds it should be able to deserialize it again.. I really don't want to write a [custom deserializer](http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/how-to-serialize-java-util-date-with-jackson-json-processor-spring-3-0/) for this which I then have to declare for every Date property on client and server side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we decided to work around the problem and have our client create formatted date strings to send to the REST server using a custom

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
```